# Are different "topological" AdS spacetimes isometric?

Tags: general-relativity, topology, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, diffeomorphism-invariance

In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9808032 the author says that black holes in AdS spacetimes can have horizons with different topologies. In particular, when the black hole mass $M$ vanishes, we are left with different kinds of AdS spacetimes. Author also says that these spacetimes are *locally isometric*.

To make the question clearer (and maybe easier to answer), I start with the Einstein equations with negative cosmological constant in 4 spacetime dimensions:

\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}-\frac{3}{L^2}g_{\mu\nu}=0\:.
\end{equation}

The two metrics
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-\frac{r^2}{L^2}dt^2+\frac{L^2}{r^2}dr^2 + \frac{r^2}{L^2}(dx^2+dy^2)\:\:\:\:\:\text{(usual AdS)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
ds_1^2=-\left(1+\frac{R^2}{L^2}\right)dT^2+\left(1+\frac{R^2}{L^2}\right)^{-1}dR^2+R^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta) d\varphi^2)
\end{equation}
are both solutions of the Einstein equations above (you can explicitly check it using Mathematica). If I understood things well, there may be a diffeomorphism (coordinate transformation) $(t,r,x,y)\to(T,R,\theta,\varphi)$ relating the two metrics. Can anyone spot this diffeomorphism, or at least give an argument of why the two metrics are the same up to a coordinate transformation?

**Notice**: I know that two solutions of the Einstein equations are not said to be related by a coordinate transformation (e.g. Minkowski and Schwarzschild), but, as I said before, the author claims that in this case the two solutions (spacetimes) are locally isomorphic.

**Notice 2**: Also $ds_2^2=-\left(-1+\frac{R^2}{L^2}\right)dT^2+\left(-1+\frac{R^2}{L^2}\right)^{-1}dR^2+R^2(d\theta^2+\sinh^2(\theta) d\varphi^2)$ satisfy the same Einstein equation.